# SSL authentication with Cassini

Tags: ios, iis, ssl, nsurlconnection, cassini

can we use following methods for ultra cassini ? as i know it is very well with IIS

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
  return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
  if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
      [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

  [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Cassini has the level of authentication built into it, but I'm a bit doubtful.  I'm pretty sure you should be able to use IIS Express, which will be replacing Cassini.

Check out [Scott Guthrie's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) about IIS Express.

Comment: you are right, Cassini dont have authentications and HTTPS, also i found for HTTPS one can use HttpVPN proxy with ultiDev Cassini web server ...and thank you for link and your comment.